# How to configure different loads on slave machines in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Can someone please tell me the process to configure different load on slaves machines?
I would like to set different number of threads for different slaves.

Slave 1 - 60 threads
Slave 2- 100 threads
Slave 3- 200 threads

Also how does jmeter master manage load on slaves. If i have 1000 threads and 4 slave machines, would Jmeter run 250 threads on each slave machine?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by slave? different machines, different instances, different load testing targets please elaborate

Comment: I am referring to master-slave distributed load setup in jmeter? Basically running tests on different machines and controlling them from the master machine

Comment: maybe this is useful, http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: I've already gone through the manual and i'm able to perform testing in the distributed environment. I want to know How to control the load on different slaves with the master. Unfortunately that is not described in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter do not share its load between slaves.
The slaves will also get copy of your plan and execute them individually from respective slaves.
If you use 1 thread and 100 loops with 3 slaves, total number of hits would become 300 (100 from each slave).

Answer (score 0):

Execute JMeter from command line, non-gui mode. Provide the slave, thread count etc..from command line. This way you can have control on the thread count per slave.

Comment: Can you please give an example of the commands you're talking about. Thanks

Comment: Check section 2.4.7 of http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html for full list of command line options. For your requirement, use -n to execute JMeter in non-gui mode, -J to pass thread count as a parameter into the test plan, which you can then use as variable inside the test plan, use -R to specify the jmeter slave to be used to execute the test. Using these command line options you can execute different load on different slaves. Hope you get the idea.